# String replacement better approach

Tags: string, algorithm, replace

Given a string, if there are two adjacent `'a'` it into `'a'` and if there is one `'b'` turn the `'b'` into `"bb"`. For example, `"aabbaaa"`->`"abbbbaa"`

I am thinking of either doing.

1. Use string builder and append whenever `str[i] == str[i+1] and str[i] =='a'`.This seems very trivial problem if string builder is used.
2. Or, take a character array twice the size of the string(based on the case when all the characters in the string are `'b'`) and keep assigning based on the above condition.

Is that it? or can it be done more efficiently?

Comment: There's `java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?:a(a))|(b)").matcher("aabbaaa").replaceAll("$1$2$2")` - choose language tags, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the string builder is the better option, but your algorithm as outlined needs a bit of work.

Instead of what you have, what I'd suggest is this. First, have a boolean variable saying whether you skipped the previous letter. Call it... `skippedLast`, and initialize it to `false`. Then, while iterating over the string at each spot i:

If `((i > 0) && (! skippedLast) && (str[i-1] == 'a') && (str[i] == 'a'))`, then set `skippedLast` to `true`. Else, set `skippedLast` to `false` and add `str[i]` to the output.

If `str[i] == 'b'`, then add `str[i]` to the output again.

(Of course, if you're in java and looking for "shortest code", simply doing `.replace("aa", "a").replace("b", "bb")` should work)

Comment: With SB I thought the problem is trivial and didn't think through. Nice idea with the skippedlast.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regex. If you have perl installed:

```
echo aabbaaa | perl -ne '$_ =~ s/aa/a/g; $_ =~ s/b/bb/g; print'
```